# custom PHP -URL rewriting in htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on xampp to rewrite URL for wordpress site. I am not getting the idea how to rewrite URL permanently. When I add rewrite permanent rule then my site go into directory such as

`http://localhost:8080/D:/server/htdocs/site/book`

Rule: `RewriteRule ^book$ ?product=book [R=301,NC]`

How can I write rule that automatically redirect the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's something a little fishy about your server URL. Are you *sure* that your server URL serves from the D drive under `localhost`? This would be something I'd be more expecting to see (especially with XAMPP, where htdocs is  the server root):

`http://localhost:8080/site/book`

So see if that fixes the issue first. If that doesn't work, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled. I'm not sure how to do this on Windows, but on Linux (and probably Mac, too), the command is `a2enmod rewrite` followed by `service apache2 reload`.

Comment: yes. rewrite mode is  enable. can you let me know how to do permanent rewrite. I have studies search many forum but not getting idea?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/site/book this is url that is working for other url but when apply [R=301,NC] command then url pick up the directory address

Comment: Also have an other issue  .. can  you guide?